# What kind of work is required to cut into this wall above the fireplace?

Tags: walls, fireplace, television

I recently purchased a condo unit.  I'm bothered by how thick the wall containing the fireplace is, and I saw another unit some floors above solved that problem by cutting above the fireplace to create a spot for the TV.  What kind of work is required to replicate this?

How it looks: https://i.imgur.com/v9YbYt6.jpg
How I want it to look: https://i.imgur.com/FrCyWld.jpg

Thank you!

Comment: Leaving that box along the ceiling like that seems odd for wood framed construction. Is the ceiling concrete? You might cut the cost part before people start voting to close your question. The Q&A is for subsequent readers also, and cost estimates don't age well and clutter things up for readers outside your locale.

Comment: that box possibly hides services for the floor above, or might just be a place to mount the downlights.

Comment: I'm guessing from the pictures that OP's condo is pretty high up.  To me that means it's probably concrete or steel framed construction.  Based on this, the box above the fireplace may be just to provide room for the lights and their wiring.

Comment: What's the wall made out of?  hollow plaster or solid brick?

Comment: And the walls around the fireplace are interior to the condo? Not a partition shared with a neighbor? It's framed with steel studs?

Comment: Cost is off-topic. It varies too much with location and time to be a useful question on a site of this nature. Ask your neighbors about that.

Comment: Frame challenge: Probably not the best place to put a TV.

Comment: The wall is interior and shared with a bedroom, so not shared with a neighbor.  This is concrete construction.  The wall is plaster.  If I'm thinking correctly and as someone else suggested, it's likely hollow and contains cabling.  What are some other scenarios to consider before doing any work?  Thank you!  Cost question removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, since you live in a condo which is probably a "Strata Condominium", that means that you need the Strata board's approval to renovate. You don't want to start cutting into the wall and affect your upstairs neighbour's unit; and you certainly don't want to potentially alter the structure of the building.

The noise, dust, tools, etc from your renovation will be noticed by other folks living in the building and if you don't get approval from the Board, you could be in for some hefty fines.

Even better, the Board will be able to provide you with the drawings for your unit and you'll be able to see exactly what is going on with the wall before you start cutting.

It may be that, if this is entirely an interior wall that doesn't share any side with any other unit, you're fine to alter it without approval -- but I doubt it; and it can't hurt to get the plans for your unit anyway. So reach out to the Board.  Once you've done that, come back here with the drawings and we can help you.

Comment: Thank you, this is a great starting point - I'll contact the strata board for drawings and then approval moving forward.